# Octave does not plot

Tags: plot, octave

When I try to plot a graph on GNU Octave, and try to use plot, it gives me the following output

```
set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1" size 560 420  font "*,6" dashlength 1
                  ^
     line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.9.2. 
I have tried using

```
octave:79> setenv("GNUTERM","X11")
```

but I still get the same error.

Comment: What happens when you type `set terminal` like it suggests?

Comment: A syntax error happens.

Comment: `>> set terminal
error: invalid conversion from string to real N-d array
error: set: expecting graphics handle as first argument
`

Answer (score 268, accepted):

`setenv("GNUTERM","qt")` in your octave command prompt, it should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I am more interested in what is going on. Mind explaining a bit?

Comment: Hey Cheng, I get a new error after using the command. Qt terminal communication error: select() error 9 Bad file descriptor.     How to revert to default?

Comment: Thanks it works. Why does this solve the problem? What is qt?

Comment: It works, but every time I start a new octave session, I need to type the command again to plot figure.

Comment: To use this every time you can add this command to the 'octaverc' file in the octave startup folder.  On osx el capitan mine is at '/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/site/m/startup/'.

Comment: I guess `qt` means `query or set` according to [Introduction-to-Plotting](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Introduction-to-Plotting.html#Introduction-to-Plotting) and [Graphics-Toolkits](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Graphics-Toolkits.html#Graphics-Toolkits)

Answer (score 9):

I think your problem comes from using the CLI.

As of January 2, 2014.  If you're using OS/X 10.9 (Maverics) then you can opt to use integrated GUI from the binary package by downloading the [Octave 3.8.0 .dmg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20MacOSX%20Binary/2013-12-30%20binary%20installer%20of%20Octave%203.8.0%20for%20OSX%2010.9.1%20%28beta%29/).  Use Octave-gui not Octave-cli, or otherwise start the GUI from the CLI.

#### A note about the gui from [The Octave Home Page](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html)

> But because it is not quite as polished as we would like, we have decided to wait until the 4.0.x release series before making the GUI the default interface (until then, you can use the --force-gui option to start the GUI).

Comment: Can you please explain why it works on gui and not on cli?

Answer (score 7):

The following worked out for me

1. Uninstall any existing gnuplot on your OSX

   `brew uninstall gnuplot`
2. Install gnuplot with either X or X11

   `brew install gnuplot --with-x`
3. Finally, set the GNUTERM to X11

   `setenv("GNUTERM","X11")`

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Had to use `brew-install gnuplot --with-x11`, since `--with-x` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

And if you need Aqua terminal instead of X11 - this might help:

`brew uninstall --force gnuplot`

`brew install gnuplot --with-aquaterm --with-qt4`

You don't need to add **setenv("GNUTERM","X11")** or add GNUTERM env.var to octaverc file.

Comment: You have a typo in your first command ("unintall" should be "uninstall").

Comment: Thanks @Andi for figuring that out.

Comment: Just an additional note: *you need Aquaterm installed before you run the latter Brew command* for this to work. But if you don't have it, you should be notified about that during the installation and just need to install Aquaterm and then do these steps again.

Answer (score 2):

I've got this problem too and solved by installing an [Aquaterm for mac](http://aquaterm.sourceforge.net) as mentioned [here](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Using_Aquaterm_with_Gnuplot).

p.s. If you get warnings like "warning: could not match any font: *-normal-normal-10" as I did, try to check your /usr/local/etc/fonts/fonts.conf

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

To install it without aquaterm:

```
brew cask install xquartz
brew install gnuplot --with-x
brew install octave

vim ~/.octaverc
setenv("GNUTERM", "X11")
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
```

Comment: `$brew install gnuplot --with-x`
Error: invalid option: --with-x

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when using Octave-cli, and I just avoid this by using "Octave-gui".

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Aquaterm.

```
sudo wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tuvistavie/8466870/raw/9064b4b3dfb3644950b6f5745056f54f8d6e56c6/gnuplot.rb -O /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/gnuplot.rb

brew uninstall gnuplot
brew update && brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/science
brew info gnuplot

brew reinstall gnuplot --aquaterm --qt --test
```

worked for me [ref](https://gist.github.com/tuvistavie/8466870)