# Octave freeze when it needs to plot

Tags: macos, plot, gnuplot, octave

I have a problem ploting from Octave. Octave and Gnuplot are installed with Homebrew on OS X El Capitan, and after trying to do first plot, I got error:

> set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1" size 560 420  font
>   "*,6" dashlength 1

This problem is fixed using instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18603167/1600108), in short:

```
brew uninstall gnuplot

sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/AquaTerm.framework/Versions/A/AquaTerm /usr/local/lib/libaquaterm.dylib
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/AquaTerm.framework/Versions/A/AquaTerm /usr/local/lib/libaquaterm.1.0.0.dylib
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/AquaTerm.framework/Versions/A/Headers /usr/local/include/aquaterm

brew install gnuplot --with-aquaterm
```

echo '

Now, when I do plot, eg. `plot(rand(3))`, then Octave just freeze, so I have to do Control-C to abort. When I try to plot directly from Gnuplot and `set term aqua`, it works and I get plots. But in Octave, when I want to `set term aqua` or `set term`, it reports:

> error: invalid conversion from string to real N-d array error: set:
>
> expecting graphics handle as first argument

Also, I tried with:

```
echo -E "setenv('GNUTERM','X11')" > ~/.octaverc
```

but that did not help either. I think the problem is with graphics_toolkit, but I do not know how to resolve this.

```
octave:1> graphics_toolkit aqua
```

> error: graphics_toolkit: aqua toolkit is not available
>
> error: called from
>       graphics_toolkit at line 81 column 5

```
octave:2> graphics_toolkit fltk
```

> error: graphics_toolkit: fltk toolkit is not available
>
> error: called from
>       graphics_toolkit at line 81 column 5

## Update

Accepted solution works up until version `4.2.0-rc2`, so now check the [update in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976757/1600108) for more information.

Comment: Can you check if AppNap gets activated for Octave and/or gnuplot? Open ActivityMonitor and add the AppNap column

Comment: On @Andy, it does not. It remains 'no' for octave. Same goes for gnuplot.

Comment: @miller Can you state which octave version you were using (`$ octave --version` or `version()`) ?  It would be helpful for others since there are some version-specific issues

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I noticed when I enter command `available_graphics_toolkits` it only shows

> ans =
>
> {
>
> [1,1] = gnuplot
>
> }

and wheh I try with `loaded_graphics_toolkits`, it prints

> ans = {}(1x0)

I guesed problem was with not loading GUI environment, so Octave was then recompiled with `--with-gui` option

```
brew reinstall octave --with-gui
```

and that solved a problem.

## Update

According to this [commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/commit/221df1c466444bb1e2944bee37fe240cc359399e), from last September, version 4.2.0-rc2, `--with-gui` does not work anymore. So the best it to follow the instruction from [Konstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40971175/1600108).

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer from miller didn't work for me, although `available_graphics_toolkits` and `loaded_graphics_toolkits` returned similar results. The octave package doesn't seem to have a `--with-gui` flag anymore.

Instead what I had to do to get it working was first `brew reinstall gnuplot --with-x11` and then create a `~/.octaverc` with the content

```
setenv("GNUTERM", "X11")
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
```

I did have X11 preinstalled.

Comment: This was a good hint. I had to switch from the graphics toolkit 'qt' to the 'gnuplot' and that stopped it from hanging.

Answer (score 4):

> The first plot after starting Octave 4 can last a while.

Reference: [http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_macOS_(outdated))

Answer (score 1):

I had to update octave from 4.4.0 to the latest version 5.2.0 to get out of this.
But I still can't figure out why the previous version misbehaved in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

setenv("GNUTERM","qt") from octave command line solved the problem for me!
See Cheng answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24596336/7190647