# Homebrew/brew not taking options when installing gnuplot

Tags: macos, gnuplot, homebrew

I am having a problem where I can't specify options for installing a formula with brew.

Specifically

`brew install gnuplot --with-qt` results in a `invalid option: --with-qt` and when I look at `brew info gnuplot` there is no option available:

```
$ brew info gnuplot
gnuplot: stable 5.2.6 (bottled), HEAD
Command-driven, interactive function plotting
http://www.gnuplot.info/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gnuplot.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gd ✔, libcerf ✔, lua ✔, pango ✔, qt ✔, readline ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

However, I get all indication from the [documentation](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnuplot), and [thousands of Andrew Ng's machine learning course students](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898609/octave-does-not-plot) that there are some optional flags I could specify. I've tried all sorts of updating and upgrading, and nothing under `brew doctor` seems to be relevant. I've installed very many things with brew in the past (though ultimately I'm not very sure of the inner workings)

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.0.1
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 1204; last commit 2019-02-09)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 8d29a; last commit 2019-02-09)
```

`mac os 10.14.2 Mojave`

Any ideas on where to start investigating would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, options have been removed <s>recently</s>, more about it can be found here: [Remove all options from Homebrew/homebrew-core formulae](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510)

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to use **[`MacPorts`](https://www.macports.org)** as it's generally much easier to install.

```
$ port variant gnuplot
gnuplot has the variants:
[+]aquaterm: Enable AquaTerm terminal
[+]luaterm: Enable lua-based terminals
   old_bitmap_terminals: Enable PBM (Portable Bit Map) and other older bitmap terminals
[+]pangocairo: Enable cairo-based terminals
   qt: Enable qt terminal with Qt 4
     * conflicts with qt5
   qt5: Enable qt terminal with Qt 5
     * conflicts with qt
   universal: Build for multiple architectures
[+]wxwidgets: Enable wxt terminal
[+]x11: Enable X11 support
```

> ***Note***: In the description it states that `qt` conflicts with `qt5`, so you'll want to use one or the other.

So based upon that output you can see there are several "[variants](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.variants.html)" available to install. To use `qt`:

```
$ sudo port install gnuplot +qt
```

If you also wanted to install `x11` with `qt` you could do:

```
$ sudo port install gnuplot +qt +x11
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, the option `--with-qt` is applied by default when you do `brew install gnuplot`.

As you can see in the following source code of gnuplot hombrew formula.

```
args = %W[
      --disable-dependency-tracking
      --disable-silent-rules
      --prefix=#{prefix}
      --with-readline=#{Formula["readline"].opt_prefix}
      --without-tutorial
      --disable-wxwidgets
      --with-qt
      --without-x
    ]
```

```
system "./configure", *args
```

This can be changed in the future. You can check the source code of gnuplot formula here:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gnuplot.rb